# Upgrading Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, I got this error at boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, acpi

When I upgraded Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, I got this error at boot. The laptop boot time changed from half a minute to 3 to 4 minutes. I want to know how to solve this problem, I am a new user of Ubuntu.

[image]

```
0.701900] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

0.908859] ACPI BIOS Error. (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO. GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM.AFN7],AE_NOT_FOUND

0.908940] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB PCIO.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) 
(20210730/psparse-529)v/nvme1n1p2: clean, 1771495/61022208 files , 34311329/244059136 blocks

4.193691 nvidla-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000

4.1194301 ucsi_ccg 2-0008: i2c transfer failed -110

4.1194731 ucsi.cCg 2-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

Comment: I didn't reinstall, I did the upgrade as prompted by the system.

Comment: I installed the Ubuntu system last summer, so it could be 20.04 or 21.04.

Comment: Thank you! I'll revise my question.

Comment: See if you can disable ACPI in your BIOS.  That is failing on the LCD Brightness Control Module (BCM).  You may have to try `nomodeset` for your grub to get past this.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: I've set up nomodeset, but the Lenovo notebook bios doesn't offer the ability to disable ACPI. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: With the `nomodeset` you can try also adding `acpi=off` to the `/etc/grub/default` file as well.  Make sure that you run `sudo update-grub` before rebooting the system.

Comment: ACPI has not reported errors, but there are still these errors. Booting always goes black for two minutes.`[0.505865] integrity: Problem 1oading X.509 certificate -65
dev/nvme1n1p2: clean, 1788842/61022208 flles , 34540926/244059136 blocks
[2.908797] nvidla-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c t meout error e0000000
[2.9088291] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c transfer failed - -110
[2.9089021] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
[  3.509761]j genirq: Flags mismatch irg 0, 0000080 (snd_hda_intel:card0) vs. 00015a00 (timer)
[3.5098031] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00,1: unabie to grab IRQ 0, disabling device`

Comment: I don't think disabling ACPI is a good idea because it causes me other problems. I can't view my battery and use my touchpad.

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled or disabled in BIOS?  It should be disabled.  The `acpi` was only a suggestion because your boot does show `ACPI Error`, but you might have a corrupted install as well.  One other way to tell is to boot to a Live CD/DVD/USB and see if it completes boot.